# Starting an automatic for the lazy mechanic

Tags: automatic-transmission, wiring, relay

I have an ignition problem with my 1985 Mk1 Golf Cabriolet Automatic (1.6 EW engine).  I was watching a YouTube video where the mechanic was testing the crank position sensor in on of these cars (it's contained within the body of the distributor) and he grabbed a relay which I assume was part of the interlock circuit, bridged two pins and the car started.

I know that he had the car in Park, had the keys in the ignition and in the "run" position but I would like to know which pins he bridged.  I assume it's similar to making the exciter cable on the starter live but the fact he did it on a relay seemed quite appealing.

Reason I ask isn't really through laziness.  The layout of my garage at the moment, coupled with the fact I've got three sets of wheels and tyres along the wall, means it's a bit of a pain to reach the ignition key without lots of climbing and squeezing into small spaces.  If I can set the key to the run position and then just bridge to pins to try to start the car, it would save me a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

If your starter relay is similar to this [relay](https://uk.farnell.com/durakool/dg85c-7011-76-1012/relay-spdt-12vdc-80a/dp/2292931?MER=bn_level5_5NP_EngagementRecSingleItem_2) on the Farnell website.
[image]

Then you need to connect the pins labelled 87 and 30 together.

Answer (score 1):

We used to use the "push button" from a Commer van connected to the battery plus and the starter solenoid...

That was a Lucas part (Prince of Darkness... :)) and capable of supplying the older solenoids that took 50A inrush etc...